# How to find top 10 countries by a measure in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I want to find top 10 countries by a `measure`

```
measure = CALCULATE(SUM(PSL[Commitment Value EUR]), PSL[PSL Flag] = "Global" || PSL[PSL Flag] = "Local") / SUM(PSL[Commitment Value EUR])
```

this `measure` is giving me correct and as expected values but when I am putting this in the filter to fetch `top N where N = 10 by this measure` , **17 countries** are getting filtered instead of 10. I have no idea where I am going wrong.

Any way to fetch top 10 countries by a measure?

Comment: a possible answer is that there are countries that share the same value for the measure. TOPN uses the top 10 values.

Answer (score 0):

```
ratio :=
DIVIDE(
    CALCULATE( SUM( tbl[sales] ), tbl[color] = "red" || tbl[color] = "green" ),
    SUM( tbl[sales] )
)
```

If you want to have the top 10 as a table:

```
TOPN( 10, ALL( country[country_name] ), [ratio] )
```

TOPN does not resolve ties. So you can go for RANKX as a measure:

```
CountryRank :=
RANKX(
    ALLSELECTED( country[country_name] ),
    [ratio],
    ,
    DESC,
    SKIP
)
```

And then filter by the CountryRank.

PS.

1. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
2. Provide sample data
3. Use meaningful names for tables and columns, do not use your production names.
4. Use Daxformatter to structure your DAX code, so others, and perhaps you, can read it.